# HTML + JQuery select all checkboxes, modify existing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Good day,

I have once in a long dark past found some code to check or uncheck all paired checkboxes.

Now I have accidentally used the code twice. And I noticed that all of the checkboxes carrying the same name get selected. Hence a matter of duplicate ID's or names.

Now I want to alter this. But as soon as I am making just a small change to the existing code the script stops working.
And I have no idea at what line the script gets "corrupted".

This is the HTML code

```
<table class="panel_checkboxes" style="top: -20px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Select ALL</th>
        <th>
        <input id="selectall" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox" type="checkbox" /><label for="selectall" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 4</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-4" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox selectedpanelsId" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="checkbox-panel-4" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 6</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-6" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox selectedpanelsId" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="6" /><label for="checkbox-panel-6" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 5</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-5" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox selectedpanelsId" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="checkbox-panel-5" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 7</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-7" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox selectedpanelsId" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="7" /><label for="checkbox-panel-7" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 3</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-3" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox selectedpanelsId" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="checkbox-panel-3" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 2</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-2" checked="checked" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox selectedpanelsId" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="checkbox-panel-2" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JQUERY code :

```
//<![CDATA[ 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectall').click(function () {
        $('.selectedpanelsId').prop('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
    });
});
function isChecked(checkboxId) {
    var id = '#' + checkboxId;
    return $(id).is(":checked");
}
function resetSelectAll() {
    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    if ($(".selectedpanelsId").length == $(".selectedpanelsId:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

    if ($(".selectedpanelsId:checked").length > 0) {
        $('#edit').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#edit').attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
//]]>
```

Now what I want is to change the ID **selectall** to **selectallLocations**
And change the class : **selectedpanelsId**  to **SelectedLocationsID**

> **Note** I have created a fiddle so you can see what I mean:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ferencik/dwj3hfpx/)

Comment: check the console to see what line has an error and what that error is

Comment: As a bit of an aside, your naming strategy is quite confusing.  You are using something with the term 'ID' in it for a class name which is simply bad practice.  You could drop the 'ID' portion of the name all together and just name it '.selected-location'.  Notice how I also dropped the plural nature as well.  A div wrapping the whole set could be called locations, but each checkbox is only relating to a single location, thus shouldn't really be plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<table class="panel_checkboxes" style="top: -20px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Select ALL</th>
        <th>
        <input id="selectallLocations" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox" type="checkbox" /><label for="selectall" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 4</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-4" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox SelectedLocationsID" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="checkbox-panel-4" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 6</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-6" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox SelectedLocationsID" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="6" /><label for="checkbox-panel-6" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 5</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-5" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox SelectedLocationsID" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="checkbox-panel-5" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 7</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-7" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox SelectedLocationsID" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="7" /><label for="checkbox-panel-7" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 3</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-3" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox SelectedLocationsID" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="checkbox-panel-3" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location 2</td>
        <td>
        <input id="checkbox-panel-2" checked="checked" class="regular-checkbox small-checkbox SelectedLocationsID" name="panels_set[]" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="checkbox-panel-2" style="margin-left: 25px;"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectallLocations').click(function () {
        $('.SelectedLocationsID').prop('checked', isChecked('selectallLocations'));
    });
});

function isChecked(checkboxId) {
    var id = '#' + checkboxId;
    return $(id).is(":checked");
}

function resetSelectAll() {
    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    if ($(".SelectedLocationsID").length == $(".SelectedLocationsID:checked").length) {
        $("#selectallLocations").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectallLocations").removeAttr("checked");
    }

    if ($(".SelectedLocationsID:checked").length > 0) {
        $('#edit').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#edit').attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Check updated [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dwj3hfpx/1/)

Comment: @Alex Hakkenberg, check is it what you want?

Comment: Hi Parkash, I couldn't accept the answer within 8 minutes. But then came a client and then my wife :P But YES!! It is!!!! Thanks a million!!